# How can I find a missing Connection String in my SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package that was copied from somewhere else and I had delete most of the connection string it has and only kept 3 of them. I checked all the steps and made sure none of the step is using a connection string other than the 3 that I have. But When I run the package it will throw me some errors saying:

> Error
>
> The connection "{96C72D18-B8B3-4FCB-96A0-4B5CC0461C10}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.

It doesn't matter when I run the package in BIDS but it will fail my job when I run it using SQL Agent Job. What can I do to find out this connection string and delete it? I have checked everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection manager must be referenced somewhere or it wouldn't be throwing that error. In my experience this should result in a red X being shown somewhere in the solution either during the design or when you try to execute it. A commonly missed place is in event handler tasks since they don't jump into view when you run the solution.

If you know which package is causing the error you can right click the package in the solution explorer and select "View code". Then do a text search for the offending GUID. DTSX files are just XML. I wouldn't recommend manually deleting the text but you should be able to identify which element is referencing the deleted connection manager.

Comment: This is really helpful! I have open the View Code and search for the missing connection string and found it in Log Providers which is rarely used. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to the Job step properties data sources tab and uncheck the offending connection?

Posted as an answer instead of a comment because I was unable to leave a comment.